# My code is printing strange characters instead of what it is meant to print

Tags: c++, string, console

I'm trying to make a simple console game, and I am making a sort of console graphics engine that draws a screen with a map and some text. For some reason the engine writes strange characters to the console, rather than what is meant to be written.

This engine takes two 2d vectors that describe the characters and colors to be used in the console. I am using `WriteConsole()` to write to the console, and using `SetConsoleTextAttribute()` to change the color of the text as I draw. For some reason, when I try to print text, it writes some really weird characters that have no relation to the characters that are meant to be printed. Colors work just fine though. My characters are stored as `TCHAR`s and my colors as `int`s.

My function to actually draw the screen:

```
void update()
{
    for (int y = 0; y < SCREEN_HEIGHT; y++) //loop through all of the tiles
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < SCREEN_WIDTH; x++)
        {
            if (screen.at(y).at(x) != buffer.at(y).at(x) && screenColors.at(y).at(x) != bufferColors.at(y).at(x)) //only draw the tile if it has changed
            {
                pos.X = x; //set coords of cursor to tile to be drawn
                pos.Y = y;

                SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdOut, bufferColors.at(y).at(x)); //set the text color
                SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOut, pos); //move the cursor to the tile to be drawn
                WriteConsole(hStdOut, &(buffer.at(y).at(x)), 1, dw, NULL); //actually draw the tile

                screen.at(y).at(x) = buffer.at(y).at(x); //update 2d screen vector (used to read what is on the screen for other reasons)
            }
        }
    }
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOut, restPos); //move the cursor away, so it doesn't look ugly
}
```

My function to write to the buffer vector:

```
void draw2dVector(int x, int y, vector<vector<TCHAR>> draw, vector<vector<int>> colors)
{
    for (unsigned int drawY = 0; drawY < draw.size(); drawY++)
    {
        for (unsigned int drawX = 0; drawX < draw.front().size(); drawX++)
        {
            buffer.at(y + drawY).at(x + drawX) = colors.at(drawY).at(drawX); // <- I found the problem. I am writing color ints to the buffer. 
            bufferColors.at(y + drawY).at(x + drawX) = colors.at(drawY).at(drawX);
        }
    }
}
```

My function to convert `string`s to `vector<TCHAR>`s.

```
vector<TCHAR> stringToTCHARvector(string str, int strLen) //convert a TCHAR string to a TCHAR vector
{
    vector<TCHAR> result;
    for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) //loop through the characters in the string
    {
        result.push_back(str[i]); //add the character to the TCHAR vector
    }
    return result;
}
```

I expect the output to look something like this:

```
###....###  Inventory:
####....##  Gold Piece
#..##...##
#......###
###.@..###
##########
```

But instead it gives me this:

```
êêêêêêêêêê  *insert strange characters here, because stack overflow doesn't 
êêêêêwwêêê  show them*
êêêêwwwwww
êêêêwwwwww
êêêêêwwwww
êêêêêwwwww
```

UPDATE:
It turns out that the problem was that I was writing the `ints` from my color vector to my `TCHAR` buffer. I have resolved the issue. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `vector<TCHAR> stringToTCHARvector(string str, int strLen)` -- This is actually a one-liner: `return std::vector<TCHAR>(str.begin(), str.begin() + strLen);`.  But did you check what `strLen` is?  Maybe it is not correct.

Comment: I am trying to turn it into a vector of individual characters, due to the way I draw on the screen, so I cannot use your suggestion

Comment: My code does exactly what your code is doing.  I guess you never realized it.  I know it seems that it doesn't because it's short, but why not see for yourself and test it?  Bottom line is that you never need to write a hand-coded loop for copying like this, and this is especially the case for `std::vector`, since `vector` has a constructor that takes two iterators, start and one past the end of a sequence.

Comment: Also, if it was more sophisticated, then `std::transform` is the algorithm function to use.  But in this case, straight copying is all that's done.

Comment: I have adopted your code, and it works just fine, but the problem of strange characters is still there.

Comment: @Awesomepotato29 How do you fill your `buffer` and how does that relate to `stringToTCHARvector`?  Can you give us something closer to a [mcve]?

Comment: I have tried replacing the character parameter in ```WriteConsole()``` to be a pre-defined ```TCHAR```, which was set to ```'a'```, and it wrote normally. Maybe the problem has something to do with the fact that I am writing non-letter characters?

Comment: Yes, so check what `strLen` is.  Also, I highly suggest you write something simple first, to test the console functions to ensure if anything you're doing even works at a basic level.  You aren't even sure where your error is, and that is probably because you have too much code and you (seemingly) are not using a debugger.

Comment: @Awesomepotato29 As you've discovered, code block formatting doesn't work in comments.  You should instead [edit] your question to add all relevant code.

Comment: `assert(isprint(buffer.at(y).at(x)));` -- In debug builds, try that line before the `WriteConsole` line.  If the program asserts, then the character is not printable, and it is your buffer that has the non-printable characters.

Comment: It is saying that ```assert``` is an undefined identifier, do I have to ```#include``` anything for this to work?

Comment: I have found and resolved the issue. Thank you for your help. See question for details.